# SCAPY PYTHON - Get 802.11 DS Status

Tags: python-2.7, scapy, wifi

I'm trying to use SCAPY to create a sniffing program to demonstrate 802.11 device association[s] and roles within an 802.11 network.

SCAPY has simple functions to identify Beacon frames, probe requests and probe responses.  I'm trying to dig a bit deeper than that and do my own evaluation based upon the DS status to show all other traffic association[s].

What I cannot do it determine how to get the value of the DS status (00, 01,10,11).  If determined, then I can handle the frame accordingly to get SOURCE, BSSID, RECEIVER, TRANSMITTER and DESTINATION to suit my code.

I have found that I should be able to get DS Status with tshark (wlan.fc.ds) so, if required, I could pass the frame to a tshark derived process; but I'd firstly like to attempt to do it all using SCAPY as I've only just started coding using SCAPY with PYTHON and I don't want to jump to other MAC frame analytical programs at the first hurdle.

In addition to creating my program to demonstrate device associations; I'm also using it as a tool means for me to learn more about 802.11, PYTHON and SCAPY therefore I wish to dig into each frame a bit, grouping them on the DS state.
Thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*Scapy*'s source code](http://bb.secdev.org/scapy/src/8290505df9ecbe4e4061f116088009dcc74dc5dc/scapy/layers/dot11.py?at=default#cl-153) reveals that the *To DS* and *From DS* values reside within `FCField` (which stands for *Frame Control* Field):

```
class Dot11(Packet):
    name = "802.11"
    fields_desc = [
                    BitField("subtype", 0, 4),
                    BitEnumField("type", 0, 2, ["Management", "Control", "Data", "Reserved"]),
                    BitField("proto", 0, 2),
                    FlagsField("FCfield", 0, 8, ["to-DS", "from-DS", "MF", "retry", "pw-mgt", "MD", "wep", "order"]),
                    ShortField("ID",0),
                    MACField("addr1", ETHER_ANY),
                    Dot11Addr2MACField("addr2", ETHER_ANY),
                    Dot11Addr3MACField("addr3", ETHER_ANY),
                    Dot11SCField("SC", 0),
                    Dot11Addr4MACField("addr4", ETHER_ANY) 
                    ]
```

Therefore, once you've got hold of a `Dot11` packet, you can inspect its *DS* status via the following code:

```
DS = pkt.FCfield & 0x3
to_DS = DS & 0x1 != 0
from_DS = DS & 0x2 != 0
```

Comment: Apologies for my last post; user error in formatting of the comments box (shall use cut and paste next time).  Slightly out of scope, but may I ask how I'd get, say bits 3 and 4 using a similar process.  I have tried slicing but that doesn’t get the values I want at the bit level.  Thanks, Bob

Comment: You can extract bits 3 and 4 with `pkt.FCfield & 0xC`. [Here](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-intermediate-en-KE1UJ/0/1) is a tutorial on bitwise operators in *Python*. May I suggest that you delete [your other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30824546/3903832) as it is irrelevant? Furthermore, since this answer solved your issue, please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) it by clicking the check-mark that is to the left of the answer. Note that you may accept only one answer per question and that there is absolutely no obligation to do this.

Comment: Is the only way to understand scapy by reading the source? The docs don't mention anything about how to access the `dot11` layer, or even mention the `dot11` itself, yet it does mention it can deep inspect 802.11. Wondering if I'm missing something obvious, or if the expectation is to go directly to the source.

Comment: Unfortunately, _Scapy_'s documentation is a bit lacking and I've found myself referring to its source code on numerous occasions.