# How to decode data from scapy Dot11 Packet

Tags: python, networking, scapy, network-security

I am writing a program that captures Dot11 Packets for network security testing, in these captured packets I get data as in the following for example:

```
<RadioTap  version=0 pad=0 len=36    present=TSFT+Flags+Rate+Channel+dBm_AntSignal+b14+b29+Ext notdecoded=' \x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xd5~\xbb*\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x02\x99\t\xa0\x00\xbd\x00\x00\x00\xbd\x00' |<Dot11  subtype=11L type=Management proto=0L FCfield=retry ID=14849 addr1=48:ee:0c:f4:b7:ea addr2=00:26:82:8e:9a:d4 addr3=48:ee:0c:f4:b7:ea SC=46176 addr4=None |<Dot11Auth  algo=open seqnum=1 status=success |<Dot11Elt  ID=220 len=46 info='7\x94' |>>>>
```

I would like to better understand the part that reads:

```
\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xd5~\xbb*\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x02\x99\t\xa0\x00\xbd\x00\x00\x00\xbd\x00
```

I get these types of packets in many different captures, I want to be able to 'decode' them to read the data. Is there a way to do this, perhaps a code sample?

Comment: The data, or payload, of Wi-Fi frames is normally encrypted in order to keep people from casually reading them.

Answer (score 5):

I decode 802.11 frames by scapy.

First, capture 802.11 frames whether by terminal or by WireShark and save as a pcap file.
And then, use scapy to parse the pcap file:

```
sniff(offline="/tmp/capture_chan11.pcap", prn=parse)
```

"parse" here is a customized function that processes each frame in the pcap file, mine is:

```
def parse(frame):
    if frame.haslayer(Dot11):
        print("ToDS:", frame.FCfield & 0b1 != 0)
        print("MF:", frame.FCfield & 0b10 != 0)
        print("WEP:", frame.FCfield & 0b01000000 != 0)
        print("src MAC:", frame.addr2)
        print("dest MAC:", frame.addr1)
        print("BSSID:", frame.addr3)
        print("Duration ID:", frame.ID)
        print("Sequence Control:", frame.SC)
        print(feature(frame))
        print("\n")
```

See more about Dot11 frame attributions:  [SCAPY PYTHON - Get 802.11 DS Status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30811426/scapy-python-get-802-11-ds-status)

Comment: What is? print(feature(frame)) Here?

Answer (score 0):

As the field name lets you guess, it contains data that cannot be decoded. If you really want to decode it, you have to either write (and maybe contribute!) your own dissector, or use Wireshark (or Tshark, same dissectors, command line interface) to parse the packet for you.

For the second option, you can use `wireshark(pkt)` from Scapy for Wireshark, and `tcpdump(pkt, prog="tshark")` for Tshark.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: since the latest development versions of scapy, those fields are now getting decoded properly.

Have a look at the github version:
https://github.com/secdev/scapy

Or download it here
https://github.com/secdev/scapy/archive/master.zip